# Archivo de configuración .cfg sólo con variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio

¿Es posible crear un archivo de configuración .cfg con este formato en lugar del XML que te permite crear Visual Studio?

```
[Settings]
  SeparatorChar = ";;"
  ColumnWidth = "003-030-005-015-004-030-030-050-003-050-020-002-010-030-010-030-030-010-007-002-050-015-002-002-010-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-"
  ExportColumns = "00-01-02-03-05-06-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-"
  ImportColumns = "99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-"
  WidthColumn = "040-485-050-120-180-079-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-000-"
  MainColumns = "00-01-02-03-05-06-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-99-"
  ToolTipDelay = 500
  SimpleToolTips = 1
  ToolTipOnRightClick = 0
  ToolTipOnSelectedOnly = 1
  ShowToolTipsInBookShelf = 1
  SortInGroupsMode = 0
  UseGroupsWhenSortingIndexes = 0
  UseGroupsWhenSortingTitles = 1
  UseTBDbThumbnailAsMainThumbnail = 1
  UseTVDbPlotoutlineAsMainPlotOutline = 1
  TVDBLanguageId = 7
  LastRanVersion = 256
  UseRelativePathsForPlayingMovies = 0
  ShowLoanDuration = 1
  SortOnLoanDuration = 1
  ShowToolBar = 1
  Bookshelf = 1
  ShowMovieDetails = 0
  AutoBackup = 2
  Last Options Page = 0
  DontUpdateTitles = 1
  Dont Overwrite Covers = 1
  Only Query New Movies = 0
  MultipleIMDBResultsMode = 1
  PrintRowColor = 16247513
  UseColoredRowsForPrinting = 1
  LoanedLabelColor = 25600
  SeenLabelColor = 139
  ToolbarButtonColor = 16309445
  Labels Color = 8388608
  Selection Text Color = 0
  Selection Color = 55295
  Even Color = 15794160
  Glow Color = 0
  Odd Color = 16777215
  LastUsedExportFile = ""
  PrintFont = "Arial"
  LastUsedTemplate = 0
  PrintFontSize = 10
  OutputPath = ""
  DatabasePath = ""
  Prefixes = "The,A,De,Het"
  CreateHTMLPatchFolder = 0
  CreateHTMLPatchFrom = 0
  CustomJPEGQualityInHtmlExport = 90
  AddYearToTitleInHtmlExport = 1
  UseThumbnailsInHtmlExport = 1
  Include3DInHtmlExport = 1
  IncludeGenresInHtmlExport = 1
  CreateBackupWhenExportingHTML = 1
  UseCustomJPEGQualityInHtmlExport = 0
  RoundPersonalRatings = 1
  ShowNumberOfVotes = 1
  ShowRatings = 0
  ShowAKAinSearchResults = 0
  FixTitlePrefix = 0
  CheckForUpdates = 1
  NumberOfLatestAdditions = 10
  EnableLoanHistory = 1
  ShowHTMLResult = 1
  HTMLSortOrder = 1
  IncludeLatestAdditions = 1
  IncludeAllMovies = 1
  ShowExport = 1
  ImportMode = 0
  UseAddMovieDefaults = 1
  UseLastFilter = 0
  UseLastSort = 1
  Language = 5
  LastUsedFilter = 34
  SortDirection = 1
  SortColumn = 0
  OnlyUnseenRandom = 1
  BrowseUseCover = 1
  IgnoreDriveLetters = 1
  BrowseUseNFO = 1
  BrowsePosponeSelection = 1
  BrowseQueryIMDB = 1
  BrowseUseFirstEntry = 0
  BrowseRecursive = 1
  OverriddenGenres = "||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||"
  AlternativeTitleSearch = 0
  MatchWholeWordSearch = 0
  MatchCaseSearch = 1
  LastUsedTitleSearch = "Venganza"
  PlotOutlineLanguageTMDb = 0
  ShowSeasonInfoInTVSeriesNames = 1
  ShowCharacters = 1
  ShowTopAfterSorting = 0
  TMDbPlotOutlineFallback = 1
  ImportPlotOutlineTMDb = 0
  ImportThumbNailTMDb = 0
  ImportMovieTrailerTMDb = 0
  ImportMovieTrailer = 1
  TitleType = 1
  Import Thumbnail FreeCovers = 0
  Import Thumbnail MovieMeter = 0
  Import Thumbnail = 1
  CertificationCountry = "USA"
  ImportDuration = 1
  ImportLanguage = 1
  ImportCountry = 1
  ImportYear = 1
  ImportAwards = 1
  ImportCertification = 1
  ImportAlternativeTitle = 3
  ImportPlotOutline MovieMeter = 0
  ImportPlotOutline = 1
  ImportRating = 1
  ImportNrActors = 5
  ImportDirector = 1
  ImportGenres = 1
  UseActorsWithPictureFirst = 1
  ImportAspectRatio = 1
  ImportActorPhotos = 1
  ImportActors = 1
  ShowTVSeriesBoxes = 1
  MediaInfoPath = ""
  UseMediaInfo = 0
  IgnorePrefixOnTitleSort = 1
  CustomBackground = ""
  CustomBackgroundOffset = 0
  BookShelfStyle = 3
  DVDBOX_MARGIN = 6
  UseFixedGlowColors = 1
  ShowBluRayBoxes = 7
  BookshelfShowSeen = 1
  BookshelfShowLoaned = 1
  BookshelfShowTitles = 1
  BookshelfShowNumbers = 0
  NumberDisplayMode = 0
  ShowSeenMode = 0
  IgnoreKeywords = 1
  IgnoreKeywordsString = "Trailer"
  DefaultThumbnail = ""
  RenameMediaFormat = "%T (%C, %Y) %V %3"
  UseFolderName = 0
  RenameMediaAll = 0
  Renumber = 0
  EnableDelete = 0
  ProxyServer = ""
  PosterMode = 1
  UseProxy = 0
  Skin = ""
  ScreenFont = "Tahoma"
  ZoomFactor = 100
  DoubleClickMode = 0
  ScreenFontSize = 8
  ShowReservedPositions = 1
  SortSecondaryColumn = 1
  DeleteMediaFiles = 0
  NrLimitNumberOfMoviesToAdd = 10
  LimitNumberOfMoviesToAdd = 0
  CurrentDatabase = 0
  Databases = "*"
  cy = 665
  cx = 987
  y pos = 164
  x pos = 638
  WindowState = 0
  LastUsedSearchTab = 0
  LastSaved = "42584.825799"

  [Paths]
  BrowseHD = ""

  [Defaults]
  SoundLanguages = ""
  SoundTypes = ""
  Features = 0
  SeenOwnWishList = 0
  Region = 0
  System = 0
  SubtitleLanguages = ""
  Languages = ""
  Case = 0
  Media = 0
  Source = 0
  AspectRatio = 0
  Codec = 0
  Location = ""
  Resolution = "720×576 (PAL DVD)"

  [Custom Settings]
  CustomField2 = "Campo 2"
  CustomField1 = "Campo 1"
  Language 5 = ""
  Language 4 = ""
  Language 3 = ""
  Language 2 = ""
  Language 1 = ""
  Genre 5 = ""
  Genre 4 = ""
  Genre 3 = ""
  Genre 2 = ""
  Genre 1 = ""
```

Comment: La respuesta corta: sí.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese archivo `.cfg` que mencionas me suena a la estructura de un `.ini`

[INI (extensión de archivo)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_(extensi%C3%B3n_de_archivo))

Si bien ese formato esta algo anticuado existen librerias que permiten trabajarlo

[ini-parser](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser)

agregas la referencia usando nuget

Despues solo seria

```
var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
IniData data = parser.ReadFile("nombrefile.cfg");

string separatorChar = data["Settings"]["SeparatorChar"];
```

de esta forma tomas el valor y puedes escribir usando

```
data["Settings"]["SeparatorChar"] = ".";
parser.WriteFile("nombrefile.cfg", data);
```